# Getting "String or binary data would be truncated", when retrieving data via a LINQ query which uses CONTAINS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I am using ASP.NET 4.5, LINQ and EF6.1/SQL Azure.

Just started to get a problem in Production with the error message "String or binary data would be truncated".

I can cure the problem by removing this from the LINQ query in question:

```
Model.Pattern.Contains(r.Value)
```

So there is obviously something with "contains" that is causing the issue.

The DB data looks fine.

So why might "Model.Pattern.Contains(r.Value)" cause this error?

I have been scratching my head on this for about 3 hours.... Obviously missing something.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

EF - "Pattern" is string and "Value" is string.

DB - "Pattern" is varchar(max) and "Value" is nvarchar(max).

EDIT2.

Slightly convoluted LINQ to describe issue of retrieving all records.

```
db.Supplier.Where(r=>r.Category.Name=="Food" && r.SupplierType.Code=="ShortValue" && Model.Pattern.Contains(r.Value))))
```

Possible solution

```
db.Supplier.Where(r=>r.Category.Name=="Food" && r.SupplierType.Code=="ShortValue" && Model.Pattern.Contains((r.Value.Length > 4000) ? r.Value.Substring(0, 4000) : r.Value)))))
```

Comment: What is the column length of `Pattern` and what is the string length of `Value`, does the `Value` length is greater than `Pattern` Length ?

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have added in those details above.

Comment: NVarchar supports multi-byte encoding, while Varchar is mono-byte.  Possibly there's an issue with comparing different encodings?

Comment: It may be something to do with the DB data, as I have just restored last night's DB, and the code works fine with that. However the new record from today also look fine.... So still really puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely the length of the string in `r.Value`.

`xxx.Contains("abcd")` is converted to `WHERE xxx LIKE '%abcd%'` in SQL, and there is a limitation in SQL Server which says that the `LIKE` argument can't be longer than 8000 bytes (or 4000 Unicode nvarchars). More info can be found in this question:
[4000 character limit in LIKE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751037/4000-character-limit-in-like-statement)

Try the following two queries to confirm:

```
var shortSearch = "aaaaa";
var longSearch = new string('b', 10000);

var shortResults = ...Model.Pattern.Contains(shortSearch)... //Should be OK
var longResults = ...Model.Pattern.Contains(longSearch)...   //Should cause an error
```

I haven't used Linq-to-Entities, but in Linq-to-SQL, the search parameter is converted to an `nvarchar(4000)` in the SQL query, which obviously would cause *truncating* "longSearch" if the query was to be executed.

Comment: superb, thanks, this was my issue.However it highlighted an issue with my LINQ as well. I have added a version of it, to my question,  to illustrate the point. Basically all records, whether they contains short values or long values are filtered, although I hope my query would prefilter the short values first ie brackets before applying the CONTAINS.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to optimize the query by having it fetch all "Food"/"ShortValue" suppliers *before* it starts the more time-consuming task of searching through `Model.Pattern`? Are you sure the SQL execution plan doesn't take care of that for you?